# Is there any connection between Lagrange points and the icosahedron?

Tags: polynomials, classical-mechanics, polyhedra, physics

Given the Newtonian two-body problem, one can ask if there are any orbits that allow a test particle to maintain a fixed configuration relative to the two bodies. In other words, in a frame that rotates with the two-body system, the test particle looks like it always remains at the same point. Such points do exist, are called [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point), and it's not difficult to convince oneself (correctly!) that there are five of them.

Now, to find all Lagrange point locations one needs to solve a quintic. Given that we know the solution of the quintic is closely connected with the icosahedron, it occurred to me to wonder whether the icosahedron can be connected with the problem of finding Lagrange points in some honest sense (i.e., not just via the quintic).

I couldn't see a way to make a connection but I could believe it exists. Can anyone else see one?

Comment: Not all Lagrange points are associated with that quintic solution. Only the three collinear with the two masses are. The other two, in the equilateral-triangle positions, are not involved in the quintic equation.